# Simple animation is not running smoothly

Tags: java, animation, processing

I have a very simple [Processing](https://processing.org/) application to move a rectangle across the screen:

```
void setup() {
    size(800,600);
    thread("updateState");
    frameRate(100);
}

void draw() {
    background(#FFFFFF);
    rect(800f - position, 300f, 50f,30f);
}

float position = 0;
void updateState() {
  while(true) {
      position  = position < 850f ? position + 1f : 0f;
      delay(10);
  }
}
```

If I move the object 1 pixel at a time it's quite smooth, I understand this to be because the update thread is in sync with the framerate, more or less, so there's little stutter.  However, to increase the speed to 4 pixels it's not very smooth:

```
position  = position < 850f ? position + 4f : 0f;
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: It's not clear to me which java animation framework you're using.

Comment: It's called `processing` (https://processing.org/).  It's a pain they chose a verb as their name, it makes it hard to use clearly in a sentence!

Comment: How are you drawing? Where? You will need to make a 'render loop', probably.

Comment: The render loop is handled by the framework (https://processing.org/).  I perhaps shouldn't have added the `Java` tag...

Comment: I don't know Processing. I think you will need to add pixels 'by time'. You will need to know how much time has passed from last render/update... and multiply that by velocity (pixels/sec for instance). If you add N pixels like you do... I don't think that will be smooth. Maybe you can access that time/delay and multiply by that... .somehow. Just an idea.

Comment: @gorlok Thanks for the pointer, I appreciate it.  I'm quite new to animation techniques!

Comment: Decrease delay instead of speed to keep smooth

Comment: Decreasing delay will produce the effect desired but will not be accurate, not will yours 1px at 100fps (1000ms/10delay), you have to keep track of the time between loops on the while and divide your speed by its seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth I do not see the stutter you're talking about, but I'll try to help in a general sense.

Why are you using a thread to update the stuff that's being drawn?

Instead of doing your own update loop, use Processing's `draw()` function, which is already called 60 times per second.

```
float position = 0;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  frameRate(100);
}

void draw() {

  position  = position < 850f ? position + 4f : 0f;

  background(#FFFFFF);
  rect(800f - position, 300f, 50f, 30f);
}
```

If you absolutely positively must use a thread for some reason, then you need to think about [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)). Basically, you need to think about what should happen if your update thread changes the `position` variable in the middle of your drawing thread using it. These issues can cause stuttering and [tearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing). this is why most UI libraries, including Processing, pretty much only use a single thread for updating and drawing.

You might also want to look into [delta timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing), where you calculate how long it's been since you last updated, and base your movements on that time instead of moving a fixed distance each frame. See [this thread](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/18478/deltatime) for a discussion on doing this in Processing.

Comment: Thanks, removing the thread has certainly helped and I can see why it's undesirable, in this instance.  Based on comments (and your answer), I've added crude delta timing and velocity and it's much better now.  My animation journey continues :)